# Twincat 3 how to use alarm table

Tags: twincat-hmi

Does anyone have manual instruction (link) step by step how to make alarm table visualization in twincat 3? Thank's
I make it not succesfully. Please help me!
I'm new comers in beckhoff technology
Not finding yet the manual instruction.

Comment: [link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplccontrol/925359883.html&id=1314131206133199522)

Comment: That is twincat 2 though, are you using TF2000 or just Twincat3 visu?

Comment: Hi ziga, at twincat 2 i had succesfully. But in Twincat 3 visu i can do as twincat 2... i wanna show a message

Comment: You will need to create a custom control and set it's text and visibility from your PLC when you want to display the message, is what my guess is.

Comment: Now i use 1. FB_simpleadsLogEvent to set an event logger. 2. FB_adsreadevent to read the event (event table reference to this FB). 3. Event configurator to create a message. If i have more than 100 message, should i have to add event one by one on event configurator. Is there more simple way that i have done.